# Storing an Old Sump or Ejector Pump for Later Use

Tags: plumbing, pump, sump-pump

I recently replaced my functioning, but of unknown age, ejector pump. After washing it, I'd now like to store it so that it could be pulled out in case of an emergency. I'm considering putting it in a bucket of water (along with a few ounces of bleach, to hopefully keep the water from getting nasty over time) and closing it with a suitable lid.  This way, everything stays wet and there's less chance of it corroding while in storage.  There are no guarantees, of course, it will work if I ever pull it back out - but a potential emergency pump is better than no possible emergency pump.

My question is: **has anyone else stored their old pump "wet"?**  If so, any suggestions /tips? Any alternative approaches? I'm slightly concerned about adding bleach (which could be somehow reactive), but can't think of a better additive to keep the water from fouling.

Comment: I'm not certain, thus a comment, not an answer: I'd think that bleach would be very hard on any rubber seals. I'd suggest chlorine, picked up at a pool supply store (in the very smallest quantity they have). As an alternative, a coating of wax, grease or vaseline will go a long way toward keeping external rust at bay while avoiding the corrosive impact of bleach, or even the chlorine, and allow you to store it dry.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for your comment.  I think pool chlorine and "bleach" are both NaOCl, although perhaps regular bleach also has some other additives. I agree with the concern about any rubber internal seals. I'm mostly concerned about internal corrosion (the external surface is already pretty crusty...), so I'd have to disassemble it to grease it down.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend using grease here either.  I doubt that this thing was intended to be greased and it may contain parts that can break down while in contact with grease.  My recommendation is that you thoroughly clean and then dry it out and store it in a dry place.  That's how it came from the factory and that's how you'll get the longest storage life out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I've never stored an ejector pump "wet" but if I wanted to do that, I'd store it in a 50-50 mix of distilled water and standard green automotive antifreeze. The antifreeze contains rust inhibitors. I've personally stored a large diesel engine with a cast iron block for five years after flushing and filling it with 50-50 green antifreeze, and at the end of that time the fluid came out perfectly clean. No rust at all. And the antifreeze won't hurt rubber parts like bleach would.

It might be good to run the pump for a few moments after immersing it to make sure all the air is pumped out of it.